# Multiple references to the same variable in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to have different ways to access the same variable. I have a bunch of objects that I store in a dict so I can iterate over them. But on occcasion I would like to access them directly (without going through the structure in the dict...)

```
object1 = someObjectContructor()
someDict = {}

someDict[1] = object1
```

Can I have the two point to the same object in memory? So that if I change something in object1 that change would be there in the the dictionary?

Comment: The code provided will work (assuming object1 is mutable). Two references to the object will be created, one in `someDict`, one in `object1`. Modifying one will modify the other. However, assigning a new value to either will break the link.

Comment: The important word is mutable. Had `object1` been a string, for instance, the answer would have been different, as strings are immutable in Python. You can verify that two objects are identical with the `id` function (and also the `is` statement).

Comment: Here is a really good [article](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)  by Ned Batchelder (the guy that brought us `Coverage`) on when python refers to the same objects and when not.  Hope this helps!

Comment: so assuming object1 has a method that would change a parameter that would work, but having something like object1 = somethingnew will break the link. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal demo showing that it works:

```
>>> object1 = []
>>> someDict = {}
>>> someDict[1] = object1
>>> someDict[1].append('foo')
>>> object1.append('bar')
>>> print(object1 is someDict[1])
True
>>> print(object1)
['foo', 'bar']
>>> print(someDict[1])
['foo', 'bar']
```

Of course if you use an *assignment* you will point to a different object:

```
>>> object1 = ['baz']
>>> print(object1 is someDict[1])
False
>>> print(object1)
['baz']
>>> print(someDict[1])
['foo', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this in the python command line:

```
object1 = 5
someDict = {}
someDict[1] = object1

print(someDict[1])
# output: 5

object1 = 6
print(someDict[1])
# output: 5
```

If you change `object1` after `someDict[1]` has been assigned it, `someDict` doesn't change.

Comment: Strings are non mutable. And anyway `object1 = 'bar'` never tries to change any object but just make the variable point to a different object.